# Table view is not displaying the comments or username from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the code I use to fetch the comments and username of users from firebase to display in my tableview cell for comments. It currently does not display anything but when I post comments it goes through and I can see it on the firebase database. I just need to read all the comment datas and display it.

```
func fetchComment()
{
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Newsfeed").child(itemSelected.title)

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.hasChild("comments")
        {
            ref.child("comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snappy in
                for comPosted in snappy.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
                {
                    let commentPosted = comment()

                    guard let comDict = comPosted.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                    else
                    {
                        continue
                    }

                    commentPosted.commentText = comDict["userComment"] as! String!
                    commentPosted.username = comDict["userId"] as! String!

                    self.comments.append(commentPosted)
                }
            })
        }
    })

    self.commentTableView.reloadData()
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt to reload the table view after getting the data from firebase?

Comment: oh sorry, I have self.commentTableView.reloadData() in there before the last line of code. It still doesnt show anything though.

Comment: You have to call `reloadData` just after the `for` loop, include the completion block. Right now you are calling `reloadData` long before the data is even retrieved.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it still doesnt display it :(

Comment: You need to provide more details. Show your updated use of `reloadData` as well as the relevant table view data source methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase  is asynchronous and therefore the code needs to allow Firebase time to return the data from the server. That data is only valid *inside the closure* and any code outside the closure will execute before the code inside. Code is much faster than the internet!

So moving the tableView.reloadData right after the for loop will ensure it executes after the dataSource array is populated.

Also, the two observe events in the code are Single events - meaning they don't stay attached to the node so the removeAllObservers is extraneous.

```
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Newsfeed")
                         .child(itemSelected.title)

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.hasChild("comments")
        {
            ref.child("comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snappy in
                for comPosted in snappy.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]
                {
                    let commentPosted = comment()
                    let comDict = comPosted.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    commentPosted.commentText = comDict["userComment"] as! String!
                    commentPosted.username = comDict["userId"] as! String!
                    self.comments.append(commentPosted)
                }
                self.commentTableView.reloadData()

                //A quick check to ensure the array is populated.
                //Can be removed.
                for c in self.comments {
                    print(c.commentText)
                    print(c.username)
                }  
            })
        }
    })
```

The above code is tested and works so if the tableview is still not displaying the data, there may be an issue in the tableView delegate functions.

Comment: @SioneSevakiFangaiuiha Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped!