# How to set property inside a block (Firebase)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, objective-c-blocks

I want to set the property "users" in the block, but outside the block function the property yields nil.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *users;

- (void)configureData {

_ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
NSString *currentUserID = user.uid;

_refHandle = [[[[_ref child:@"users"] queryOrderedByChild:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appliedByUsers/%@", user.uid]] queryEqualToValue:@YES] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (FIRDataSnapshot *user in snapshot.children) {
        [_users addObject:user.key];
        NSLog(@"first object in userArray: %@", users[0]);
    }

}];

NSLog(@"first object in userArray outside block: %@", users[0]);

}
```

What is the best practice to modify a property inside the block?

Comment: The common approach is to move the code that needs the users **into** the block.

Comment: the purpose is to use the user keys to retrieve data from another node in firebase, which would involve putting another observeEventType block into the other one. would that be an appropriate solution? if not, what is an elegant way of retrieving data from one node with information from another one? Thanks Frank!

Comment: Firebase is asynchronous and the code outside the block will run *before* Firebase has time to return data inside the block. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130730/table-view-is-not-displaying-the-comments-or-username-from-firebase/43157576#43157576) for more detailed info. You need to work with the firebase data inside the block; populate your dataSource, refresh your tableViews etc. Structure you code and UI with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_refHandle = [[[[_ref child:@"users"] queryOrderedByChild:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"appliedByUsers/%@", user.uid]]
   queryEqualToValue:@YES] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

_users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (FIRDataSnapshot *user in snapshot.children) {
    [_users addObject:user.key];
    NSLog(@"first object in userArray: %@", users[0]);
}

}];
```

this code just set a value for the block parameter. Do you know what time the block of code to perform ? you find user[0] = nil, because In the previous of performing log code, the block code is not performed.

Comment: the method "configureData" is meant to fire in viewWillAppear, I want the array "users" to contain the objects passed in the block in another method/block

Comment: outside block, user[0] = nil, but inside block user[0] is not nil? this is your problem, yes?

Comment: exactly, instead of NSLog(@"first object in userArray: %@", users[0]);, it should say NSLog(@"first object in userArray: %@", _users[0]);

Comment: oh oh, maybe you need to review block memory life cycle. how system allocate memory for block ?  _user inside block, this variable actually is not equal self.user. system would allocate some memory for _user. so _user is no relationship .so self.user is nil.

Comment: if you want block capture user property, you need move init _user code outside of block and add __block on the head. like this.
   __block  _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: ok I solved the problem when managing all the data within the block.

Comment: However, if I put  __block _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; outside the block, xcode tells me it's an incompatible pointer to integer conversion.

Comment: yes, exactly, just put _users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; outside the block, not write __block.